# TypeError when yielding tuples

Tags: python

I'm trying to return a tuple object from a generator but I keep getting an error and I can't figure out why.

My code is:

```
class Puzzle(object):
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board

    def do_somthing(self, row, col):
        //transform board - returns modified Puzzle object

    def results(self):
        for row in range(len(self.board)):
            for col in range(len(self.board[0])):
                yield ((row, col), do_something(row, col))
```

Essentially board is a `n x m` list, eg `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

The `results` function yields a tuple that includes a tuple - (row, col) - and a modified Puzzle object.

When I try to view the yielded tuples using the code

```
for coord, result in r.results():
    print(coord, result)
```

I get the error `TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2`.

I've also tried yielding the tuples by breaking up the code, ie:

```
a = (row, col)
res = (a,) + tuple(do_something(row, col))
```

but it still fails.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code would not produce that error. You **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: Try: `yield ((row, col), self.do_something(row, col))`

Comment: Your error is probably in `do_something` which for some reason you omit. All of this would be clear if you had posted the full error message including the stack trace, which you should always do for debugging questions

Comment: @Booboo that's true that the OPs code would raise a `NameError` without that, but that wouldn't explain the error the OP is seeing

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have a call to `tuple()`, so you can't get the error you've quoted.

I assume it comes from `do_somthing`, which you've elided.

Either way, I'm unable to reproduce any issue with this minimal but equivalent-ish code:

```
def results():
    board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board[0])):
            yield ((row, col), board[row][col] * 42)

for coord, result in results():
    print(coord, result)
```

It happily prints out

```
(0, 0) 42
(0, 1) 84
(0, 2) 126
(1, 0) 168
(1, 1) 210
(1, 2) 252
```